# What's a good resource for learning how to make quality wiring diagrams?

Tags: diagram, schematic

I'm almost done with my electrical engineering degree, so I understand circuits, but I want to learn how to make good quality wiring diagrams. Not pure "schematics" like you'd do in a classroom, but wiring diagrams like this example. Is there a good resource to learn how to do this? Are there "common" practices labeling wires and such? Or does each company just make it up as they go along?

[image]

Comment: From my experience each company have their own standards, software and understanding of how a wiring diagram should look like.

Comment: This is a good example of a block diagram with detailed interface specs, unlike most schematics but somewhat like those used for consumer MOBO’s. The intended reader and company standards come first in choosing the modus operandi. For good examples find those by HP and Tek.

Comment: When we outsource cables, I make the wiring diagrams in GIMP and then go back and forth with the manufacturing company to make sure that there are no questions or ambiguities.  Does it look as polished as what an expensive CAD program would give out?  Maybe not, but our cables are relatively simple and a graphics program like GIMP gives you total control instead of fighting with a CAD program if you are trying to do something it isn't designed to do.

Comment: There's lots of choices for this. The problem is portability and maintainability if you use some proprietary tool, even a free one. Choose a tool that allows clean, vector-based import into popular desktop publishing and presentation tools. Believe it or not, OrCAD's drawing tool works really well this way, at least for importing into Word. Downside: OrCAD doesn't come with drafting libraries, you'll need to create your own. Whatever you do, don't use Visio. It sucks.